# the PyQt4.QtCore module failed to register with the sip module

Tags: pyqt, qgis

I am running QGIS on Linux Fedora. Everything was fine until I upgraded to Fedora 29. Now, each time I launch QGIS or run a python script, I have the following message:

> RuntimeError: the PyQt4.QtCore module failed to register with the sip module

after I import qgis._gui. I'm not sure what it means. Is it a problem with my sip version, some path to fix? I am running QGIS 2.18.20, sip-4.19.13 and Python 2.7.15.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After unsuccessful debugging and googling about the very same issue, I've upgraded to 3.4 version from copr repository:

```
    dnf copr enable dani/qgis
    install qgis python3-qgis
```

Now python works and I can QGIS again, seems the developers are not too keen to solve 2.18 version errors.